# Right way to create connection between entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new in EF, and I have a problem.
This is the situation in my model:
a parent Entity: "**Client**" 
two children Entities: "**Private**" and "**Public**"
and another one "**Address**"

Client can have MANY ShippingAddresses
Private has ONE *HomeAddress*
Public has ONE *LegalAddress*

So, I filled the association's forms, in this way:
1) Client->Address 
   1->Many 
   [X]      [ ]
   ShippingAddresses    ......
   [X] add foreign key

2) Private->Address 
   1 -> 1 
   [X]      [ ]
   HomeAddress    ......
   .........

3) Public->Address 
   1 -> 1 
   [X]      [ ]
   LegalAddress    ......
   .........

That's all. The problem is when I try to add a simple record

```
Client client = new Private();
client.Name = "John";
client.HomeAddress = new Address();
//filling the address' properties...                    
dbContext.Clients.Add(client);
```

When I call

```
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get: 
*Entities in 'AccountingModelContainer.Addresses' participate in the 'PublicAddress' relationship. 0 related 'Public' were found. 1 'Public is expected.*

What am I doing wrong???
tnx in advance, Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a public address.

```
 client.LegalAddress = new Address().
```

Comment: Hi! I created a new Public , so I wrote what you told me. Result:
I have a validation error! "{System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}"